# Lock splitting vs lock striping

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Below is the excerpt from Effective Java by Joshua:

> If you do synchronize your class internally, you can use various
>   techniques to achieve high concurrency, such as lock splitting, lock
>   striping, and nonblocking concurrency control.

Above suggests that lock splitting and lock striping are 2 different techniques but when I tried to find the difference between I couldn't find a difference.

Is there is a difference between them or they are same thing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Lock splitting is about using different locks for different parts of a classes functionality; e.g. one lock for read operations and another one for write operations.

Lock striping is about using different locks for different parts (stripes) of the data structure that a class manages; e.g. dividing a map into submaps, each with their own locks.