# How we can take a lock ob object using ReentrantLock?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here we are taking a lock on Node object "f" and performing some update operation in synchronised way.

Could someone please let me know, how we can convert this code using ReentrantLock?

I read we can take a lock on block of code using lock() and unlock() methods but not see anywhere how we can take a lock on object.

```
public void updateNodeValue(){
    Node<K,V> f = getNode();
    synchronized (f) {
        // do something here to update the value in Node Object f
    }
}

public Node<K,V> getNode(){
    //  return NodeObject from an Array
}
```

Comment: You would need to declare a `ReentrantLock` on `Node` and lock it in place of the synchronized block.

Comment: You mean to say that 

    class Node<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    volatile V val;
    volatile Node<K,V> next;
    final Lock lock;

    Node(int hash, K key, V val, Node<K,V> next) {
        this.hash = hash;
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }
}

and the use it like Lock l = node.lock;
l.lock();
do something();
l.unlock();

In this way it will take a lock only on a particular Node object and other thread can use other Node object.

Comment: Something like that.

Comment: What you are talking will happen even with synchronized too, Thread will wait only for the locked objects, only, If thread has a different object other than the locked, it will enter in synchronized block in any case. I think what @shmosel has suggested seems to be right answer

Comment: Refer to linked question for more details. This question too provides better insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java/

Comment: This question was not answered in any other post as stated in its heading. This question is answered only in the first comment by @shmosel

Answer (score 0):

Locks are not related to instance fields. They lock the whole object in which the instance field is.

[Lock striping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123180/lock-splitting-vs-lock-striping) is an option, though.

Comment: Who said anything about instance fields?

Comment: I believe the lock is put on the instant field (instant object) but not the main object (this) itself. As the game is to get access to the locked object to execute its surrounding code block; it doesn't matter whether you are taking the locked object as a current object (this) or an instant field as long as you refer same all over your code.